# Table cell alignment with rowspan

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table with a cell that has a rowspan. Basically just a cell on the left with rowspan=2 and 2 columns on the right. I want the columns on the right side to stick to the top. However, the space on the right side is divided equally between the two columns. Adding height: 100% to the last column on the right side does the trick in Chrome, but does not work in FF or IE.

```
<table border="1" style="width: 200px;">
<tr>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Some long cell here...The point is that the Col_A and Col_B should both stick to the top. I tried adding height: 100% to the last column (Col_B) but that does only work in Chrome. Firefox puts Col_B at the very bottom while IE seems to completely ignore it.</td>
    <td>Col_A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col_B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jtr1r132/1/

**Update:**

As Pragnest suggested below, adding height: 1px to the first column on the right (Col_A) does the trick for Chrome and FF. In IE (and Edge) however it still does not work as intended.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jtr1r132/9

Comment: you want to Col_B in example 2 on top in ff, right?

Comment: i think you wanted to solve this with height:100% which is issue in FF but if you want solution to put that td on top then mention in your question or else it will be dynamic question. Thank you

Comment: I want Col_B on top in every browser if possible ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In your case you need to some alternate to achieve your output.
Like as below you need to remove height in second column and set 1 px height in first column so automatically achieve your output.

**Like change in html as per below –**

```html
    <table border="1" style="width: 200px;">
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Some long cell here...The point is that the Col_A and Col_B should both stick to the top. I tried adding height: 100% to the last column (Col_B) but that does only work in Chrome. Firefox puts Col_B at the very bottom while IE seems to completely ignore it.</td>
        <td style="height: 1px">Col_A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td >Col_B</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: @Pragnest, if  you will read the last line then you will find "Adding height: 100% to the last column on the right side does the trick in Chrome, but does not work in FF or IE." so it will be better if you add some points on that. Thank you

Comment: Yes I read that line and I unable to find required output with 100% height in second column so I got idea to achieve the output with outer-way so I added comment in my answer “you need to some alternate to achieve your output”.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, This does work in Chrome and FF, IE (or Edge) however still doesn't work. I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jtr1r132/9/

Comment: I don’t know perfect answer but yes I have one solution which will be work on all the browser. You need to create one child level DOM in your td and apply height 1px on that child DOM in place of td. Like see in https://jsfiddle.net/pragneshkhalas/jxa87ebu/